# What are the pros and cons of allowing Google Play store to automatically update apps?

Tags: google-play-store

Automatically update apps on my Android phone:

Upsides:

- Apps get new feature, bug fixes, performance improvements, etc.

Downsides:

- The UI layout or some features that I am already used to changes. Sometimes I am regret to update the app due to this.

So I set Google Play to not update the apps automatically on my old phone. Now I am getting a new phone. Are there any other pros and cons to these settings, and what are some ways to mitigate my concerns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from being automatically updated, and even if you apply updates manually, you only know about possible disadvantages once the update was done. So my recommendation goes in a different direction, namely: being able to restore the state *before* the update was applied, so you can "roll back".

For this, I recommend using **[AppMonster](http://www.appbrain.com/app/appmonster-free-backup-restore/de.android_telefonie.appmanager)** (or rather [AppMonster Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/appmonster-pro-backup-restore/com.think_android.appmanagerpro), as the Pro version can do all required stuff automatically in background, so you cannot forget it). This app automatically creates a backup of each app's `.apk` file whenever the app is installed or updated. It also takes care about only keeping a configured number of backups, so you don't risk running out of space. If you don't like an update, you then can simply launche *AppMonster* to restore a previous version.

I'm using AppMonster for years already, and can heartily recommend it. And as to your original question: I have auto-updates turned off, so I can manually decide which updates I want and which not. For some apps, I prefer the version I'm currently using for reasons like removed functionality, less overhead, and more.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you wish for your phone to operate. System updates is pretty much the only updates that are needed, app updates depend on what apps you use. If you let *every* app update at will, you will get a few issues. The first is battery life. If updates are frequent, it will pull a little extra battery. If you use cellular network, you use up your mb's, or simply drain your wallet if you don't have a locked speed\payment service. If you are using the phone while it updates, you are also likely to notice some delay or sluggish performance during the updates.

While you can select what apps update automatically, and what apps do not, I suggest it's better to simply create some sort of weekly routine to update the apps you use most. It only takes a minute or two, and if you want, you can usually select "update all" to just get it all done. Tho that is best to be done on wifi network, as cellular network can be costly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always on internet and have wifi everywere you should.

Else it is just a waste of your mb\s.

But on 3g it is impossibile because of the high costs.

Comment: Question was not about costs, but about updates rather being a step backwards from the user's point of view (removed features, new bugs).

Comment: most updates fix bugs but also add bugs. there are no bugfree programs as big as apps for your phone

Comment: Agreed. But what does that have to do with "waste of MBs" and "high costs"?

Comment: the money you spend when using 3g